# RegEx string - code with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string in this format:

```
RED-MPWMC-40486655646-024
```

How can I extract MPWMC from this string with javascript?

Comment: any rules and any try?

Comment: If you know what a regexp is, why didn't you try? Nothing difficult here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of regex here. Just split it using `-` and access the array element with index=1.

```js
var str = "RED-MPWMC-40486655646-024";
console.log(str.split("-")[1]);
```